# NextAuth - Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

Hi I'm trying to make a login system for my application. When I use the login function the application gives an error. I couldn't find a solution yet hope this way we can fix it.

I've checked the `NEXTAUTH_URL` and `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` but they seem to be okay.

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000/api/auth
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=myApp
```

My `[...nextauth]` route is in the correct location `/src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js`. Ive used the default credentials example.

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

const handler = NextAuth({
    providers:[
      CredentialsProvider({
        // The name to display on the sign in form (e.g. 'Sign in with...')
        name: 'Credentials',
        // The credentials is used to generate a suitable form on the sign in page.
        // You can specify whatever fields you are expecting to be submitted.
        // e.g. domain, username, password, 2FA token, etc.
        // You can pass any HTML attribute to the <input> tag through the object.
        credentials: {
          username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "jsmith" },
          password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
        },
        async authorize(credentials, req) {
          // You need to provide your own logic here that takes the credentials
          // submitted and returns either a object representing a user or value
          // that is false/null if the credentials are invalid.
          // e.g. return { id: 1, name: 'J Smith', email: 'jsmith@example.com' }
          // You can also use the `req` object to obtain additional parameters
          // (i.e., the request IP address)
          const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/login", {
              method: 'POST',
              body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
              headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
          })
          const user = await res.json()

          // If no error and we have user data, return it
          if (res.ok && user) {
              return user
          }
          // Return null if user data could not be retrieved
          return null
        }
      })
    ]
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

And this is the button I use to call the login page. It's just the default login page that comes with next-auth.

```
<Button color="primary" variant="flat" className="text-base" onClick={() => signIn()}>
          SignIn
</Button>
```

Anybody who had a similar issue or can help me fix this?

Comment: The error you're getting usually means that there's an error with the server and it is responding with HTML instead of JSON content. Manually examine the response, check your logs, then debug from there.